# (NEW to programming) My program calculates the final score correctly but keeps printing 'F' as grade even when the final mark is >=50

Tags: java

This program works allows the user to enter an ID number, followed by four mid term test scores and a final exam score for 5 students. It then calculates the final overall score and prints both the final overall score & grade.

The problem is even when the final score is >= 50, it still incorrectly prints the grade as F, when its suppose to print either A, B or C depending on how high the score is, or F if it's <50.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Grades {


        public static void main (String[] args) {
            Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("For the first candidate, enter student ID number followed by his/her four term test scores & final exam score");
            int id1=in.nextInt();
            double t11=in.nextDouble();
            double t12=in.nextDouble();
            double t13=in.nextDouble();
            double t14=in.nextDouble();
            double f1=in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("For the second candidate, enter student ID number followed by his/her four term test scores & final exam score");
            int id2=in.nextInt();
            double t21=in.nextDouble();
            double t22=in.nextDouble();
            double t23=in.nextDouble();
            double t24=in.nextDouble();
            double f2=in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("For the third candidate, enter student ID number followed by his/her four term test scores & final exam score");
            int id3=in.nextInt();
            double t31=in.nextDouble();
            double t32=in.nextDouble();
            double t33=in.nextDouble();
            double t34=in.nextDouble();
            double f3=in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("For the fourth candidate, enter student ID number followed by his/her four term test scores & final exam score");
            int id4=in.nextInt();
            double t41=in.nextDouble();
            double t42=in.nextDouble();
            double t43=in.nextDouble();
            double t44=in.nextDouble();
            double f4=in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("For the fifth candidate, enter student ID number followed by his/her four term test scores & final exam score");
            int id5=in.nextInt();
            double t51=in.nextDouble();
            double t52=in.nextDouble();
            double t53=in.nextDouble();
            double t54=in.nextDouble();
            double f5=in.nextDouble();
            double finalMark1=(t11+t12+t13+t14)/200*80 + (f1/100)*20; //calculcates the final score for each student
            double finalMark2=(t21+t22+t23+t24)/200*80 + (f2/100)*20;
            double finalMark3=(t31+t32+t33+t34)/200*80 + (f3/100)*20;
            double finalMark4=(t41+t42+t43+t44)/200*80 + (f4/100)*20;
            double finalMark5=(t51+t52+t53+t54)/200*80 + (f5/100)*20;
            char grade1; //creates & declares grade variables as a character for each student for storage of their respective grade
            char grade2;
            char grade3;
            char grade4;
            char grade5;
            if (finalMark1 >=75 && finalMark1 <=100); //assigns a grade to each candidate based on the range their final score falls into
            grade1 = 'A'; 
            if (finalMark1 >=60 && finalMark1 <=74);
            grade1 = 'B';
            if (finalMark1 >=50 && finalMark1 <=59);
            grade1 = 'C';
            if (finalMark1 <50);
            grade1 = 'F';
            if (finalMark2 >=75 && finalMark2 <=101);
            grade2 = 'A';
            if (finalMark2 >=60 && finalMark2 <=74);
            grade2 = 'B';
            if (finalMark2 >=50 && finalMark2 <=59);
            grade2 = 'C';
            if (finalMark2 <50);
            grade2 = 'F';
            if (finalMark3 >=75 && finalMark3 <=100);
            grade3 = 'A';
            if (finalMark3 >=60 && finalMark3 <=74);
            grade3 = 'B';
            if (finalMark3 >=50 && finalMark3 <=59);
            grade3 = 'C';
            if (finalMark3 <50);
            grade3 = 'F';
            if (finalMark4 >=75 && finalMark4 <100);
            grade4 = 'A';
            if (finalMark4 >=60 && finalMark4 <74);
            grade4 = 'B';
            if (finalMark4 >=50 && finalMark4 <59);
            grade4 = 'C';
            if (finalMark4 <50);
            grade4 = 'F';
            if (finalMark5 >=75 && finalMark5 <100);
            grade5 = 'A';
            if (finalMark5 >=60 && finalMark5 <74);
            grade5 = 'B';
            if (finalMark5 >=50 && finalMark5 <59);
            grade5 = 'C';
            if (finalMark5 < 50);
            grade5 = 'F';
            System.out.println("The final mark for candidate " + id1 + " is " + finalMark1 + " and the grade is " + grade1); // prints each student's final mark and grade
            System.out.println("The final mark for candidate " + id2 + " is " + finalMark2 + " and the grade is " + grade2);
            System.out.println("The final mark for candidate " + id3 + " is " + finalMark3 + " and the grade is " + grade3);
            System.out.println("The final mark for candidate " + id4 + " is " + finalMark4 + " and the grade is " + grade4);
            System.out.println("The final mark for candidate " + id5 + " is " + finalMark5 + " and the grade is " + grade5);

            }
}
```

Comment: You need some serious refactoring of the code here, a lot of repetitive code that can be written in a function and be called.

Comment: Remove those semicolons at the end of all your `if` conditions.

Comment: Remove the `;` from after each `if`. The `if` affects the statement that follows it, up to the first `;` (when there are no curly braces).

Comment: Welcome to learning how to program.  One of the first rules you should start learning is "Don't Repeat Yourself".  Can you find a way to not use all of those statements that look copied-and-pasted?  (Hint: a method called for each candidate)

Comment: People are a bit harsh to downvote you. Sure, your code is verbose, but it looks like you are learning and actually put in the effort to try it before asking the question. A few answers below have provided you with alternatives that will greatly reduce the amount of code needed for a good solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might want to try removing the semicolons from the end of your if statements.

```
 if (finalMark5 < 50);
    grade5 = 'F';
```

shouldn't work but

```
 if (finalMark5 < 50)
    grade5 = 'F';
```

should.

Comment: To clarify "shouldn't work": this is perfectly valid code, it's jjust that you're telling the program to execute an empty statement if the condition is true.

Comment: You're right, should have specified.

Answer (score 3):

Some refactoring of the code:

```
public static char grade(double mark) {
    if (mark >= 75 && mark <= 100) {
        grade = 'A';
    } else if (mark >= 60 && mark < 75) {
        grade = 'B';
    } else if (mark >= 50 && mark < 60) {
        grade = 'C';
    } else {
        grade = 'F';
    }

    return grade;
}
```

Now all you do in main is:

```
char grade1 = grade(finalMark1);
char grade2 = grade(finalMark2);
char grade3 = grade(finalMark3);
char grade4 = grade(finalMark4);
char grade5 = grade(finalMark5);
```

instead of the code bonanza you have now. 5 lines replace 30+ lines

Comment: This is way better than the other answer because BRACKETS! And proper refactoring. + 1

Comment: Would be even better if you didn't still repeat code five times. You could use an array of grades and a for loop.

Comment: @JHH he wold have to set up lists for students and grades and then you can for loop everything and make one function call. I wrote this assuming he doesn't have lists (which he should). It looks like he is a beginner so don't know if he knows how to use lists yet.

Comment: I am new to programming so I really don't know much yet..but this was helpful to reducing the code size..thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how to proceed here..I put the first batch of code outside of main and I get this "error: class, interface, or enum expected"..

Comment: Refactoring is equivalent transformation of code... this gives an F to anyone with score of 100, 74, 59 (unlike the original) and doesn't ever give a D (as the original)... recheck your equal signs.

Answer (score 3):

Grickus has provided you with the correct answer; you should mark his as correct.  However, your code can be easily reduced to a fraction of the size by using loops:

```
int[] students = new int[5];
char[] grades = new char[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.Println("Gimmie the student id and test scores.");
    students[i] = in.nextInt();
    double sum;
    double avg;
    // get the test scores
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        sum += in.nextDouble();
    }
    // calculate the average
    avg = sum/5.0;

    // make sure they don't have over 100%
    avg = Math.Min(avg, 100.0);

    // make sure they don't have less than 0%
    avg = Math.Max(avg, 0.0);

    // assign the letter grade
    if (avg >= 75) {
        grades[i] = 'A';
    } else if (avg >= 60) {
        grades[i] = 'B';
    } else if (avg >= 50) {
        grades[i] = 'C';
    } else {
        grades[i] = 'F';
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.Println("Final grade for "+students[i]+" is "+grades[i]);
}
```

This assumes that you will only EVER have 5 students, and each student will ALWAYS have 5 scores, no more, no less.  **Edit:** if this is not the case, you should make sure the size of the arrays are determined programmatically, and then use `i < whateverarray.length`.

Ideally, you'd have a `Student` object that holds both their id, their final score, and probably all of their other scores for reference....but that's getting ahead of the scope of this problem.

(I didn't use an IDE for this so my apologies if I missed some spelling or function call)

**Edit:**  Looks like I missed the rest of your println statement; you want the averages in there too.  Just save the avg in the same fashion and spit it out at the end.

**Edit:** Note the if statements that determine the letter grade....they don't check for upper bound values.  That's because they don't need to!  If we've already determined that avg is NOT greater than or equal to 75, then it is by definition less than 75.  We don't need to manually check for that.  This is a code optimization that would matter if there were millions of students reading data in from a database or some such thing.

Of course, if that were the case, you would not use this as written.  You'd have lists instead of arrays, and Student objects (as described above).

**Edit (for the community):** I have intentionally left `i < 5` in the for loop.  See assumption above.

Comment: This was extremely helpful in reducing the size of the code..will apply your suggestions thanks!